# R ffdf Error: is.null(names(x)) is not TRUE

Tags: r, bigdata

I'm trying to understand what a particular error message means in R.

I'm using an ff data frame (ffdf) to build an rpart model. That works fine.

However, when I try to apply the predict function (or any function) using ffdfdply, I get a cryptic error message that I can't seem to crack. I'm hoping someone here can shed light on its meaning.

```
PredictedData<-ffdfdply(x=TrainingData,split=TrainingData$id,
FUN=function(x) {x$Predicted<-predict(Model1,newdata=x)
x})
```

If I've thought about this correctly, ffdfdply will take the TrainingData table, split it into chunks based on TrainingData$id, then apply the predict function using the model file Model1. Then it will return the table (its labelled x in the function field), combine them back together into the table PredictedData. PredictedData should be the same as TrainingData, except with an additional column called "Predicted" added.

However, when I run this, I get rather unhelpful error message.

```
2014-07-16 21:16:17, calculating split sizes
2014-07-16 21:16:36, building up split locations
2014-07-16 21:17:02, working on split 1/30, extracting data in RAM of 32 split     elements, totalling, 0.07934 GB, while max specified data specified using BATCHBYTES is 0.07999 GB
Error: is.null(names(x)) is not TRUE
In addition: Warning message:
In ffdfdply(x = TrainingData, split = TrainingData$id, FUN = function(x) { :
split needs to be an ff factor, converting using as.character.ff to an ff factor
```

Yes, every column has a name. Those names contain just alphanumeric characters plus periods. But the error message makes me think that that the columns should not have names? I guess I 'm confused what this means exactly.

I appreciate any hints anyone can provide and I'll be happy to provide more detail.

Answer (score 0):

I think I found the solution to this.

Turns out I had periods in my column names. When I removed those periods, this worked perfectly.